# Android MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE, external path?

Tags: android, video

I use the `MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` intent class to capture the video, the video stored in default location(gallery),i want to store the video in specific location with specific name.

I use `MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_TITLE` and `MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_OUTPUT` but I don`t get the video at correct location, at least I need the path of recorded video.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution from Zelimir doesn't work in my case (the videos were at the right location but had a size of zero bytes). So i've found another solution:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

  if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

  try {
    AssetFileDescriptor videoAsset = getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(intent.getData(), "r");
    FileInputStream fis = videoAsset.createInputStream();
    File tmpFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"VideoFile.3gp"); 
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
        fos.write(buf, 0, len);
    }       
    fis.close();
    fos.close();
  } catch (IOException io_e) {
    // TODO: handle error
  }
```

}

The `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` and the Uri aren't necessary in this case.

Comment: the "intent" in the intent.getData() gives out null pointer exception...do you have any idea, why it might be occurring?

Comment: @ShailAdi You've probably solved this by now, but for anyone else who happens to see this: the intent will be null when you specify the `MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_OUTPUT`. If you want to use this method, remove `MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_OUTPUT` when building the intent request.

Answer (score 0):

Trick is to insert media into database before recording:

```
String fileName = "captureTemp.mp4";  
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, fileName);  
cameraVideoURI = getContentResolver()
   .insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);  

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);  
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, cameraVideoURI);  
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, MAXIMUM_VIDEO_SIZE);               
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_VIDEO_INTENT);
```

and then onActivityResult() use saved cameraVideoUri to reference recorded video:

```
String[] projection = 
   { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE }; 
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(cameraVideoURI, projection, null, null, null); 
int column_index_data =
   cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA); 
int column_index_size =
   cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE); 
cursor.moveToFirst(); 
String recordedVideoFilePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
int recordedVideoFileSize = cursor.getInt(column_index_size);
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  It did do *something*; instead of just ignoring the `EXTRA_OUTPUT` parameter, like it normally does, it created a zero-length file with the (correct name) in the `/sdcard/video` folder despite that I specified a full path name like `/sdcard/some-existing-dir/newfile.3gp`.  Complete and correct documentation on this API sure would be helpful.